# CASE if/then to trigger more/less than

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a table with names of products. Each product has multiple models. I need to us a if/then (CASE) statement to tell them if there is less than 10 or more than 10 types of a particular product.

I am thinking I need to first count the number of types so I wrote this query:

```
 select
   sum(case when Name like 'Road-650%' then 1 Else 0 End) as Road650_Count
 from Production.Product
```

What I cannot figure out is the next step where I say the result is less than 10 or greater than 10.

Here are some attempts that have failed:

Failed Attempt 1

```
  select
    sum(case when Name like 'Road-650%' then 1 Else 0 End) as Road650_Count
  from Production.Product
  where Name > 10 - 'ten'
```

Failed Attempt 2

```
  select
    sum(case when Name like 'Road-650%' then 1 Else 0 End) as Road
  from Production.Product
  if 'Road' > 10 
      Print 'More than 10 styles available'
  else
      Print 'Less than 10 styles available'
```

Comment: MySQL Or MSSQL?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what output you want. A message like in your last attempt? Or a table? Or a scalar variable?

Comment: Can you please add some sample data with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below script-

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'Road-650%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Road,
CASE 
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE 'Road-650%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 10 THEN 'More than 10 styles available'
    ELSE 'Less than 10 styles available'
END AS Result
FROM Production.Product;
```

You can also check the following script using COUNT and WHERE meet your requirement or not-

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) Road,
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 10 THEN 'More than 10 styles available'
    ELSE 'Less than 10 styles available'
END AS Result
FROM Production.Product
WHERE Name LIKE 'Road-650%'
```